# Watershed other than stream ( between two points)

Tags: grass-gis

Is there any method available to demarcate watershed for a location other than stream? I mean, if I want to find out the watershed for a place, where no stream available but, sheet of water can flow (like a causeway / Irish bridge).

Answer (score 2):

The GRASS GIS command r.watershed accepts whatever elevation model (except maybe for the perfect, not inclined planes :) ) even if it does not contains streams. It should just work...